# Error message: Object in prefixed call to "..." must be aliased

Tags: ada

I am currently reading this document: [*Ada for the C++ or Java Developer*](https://www.adacore.com/uploads_gems/Ada_for_the_C++_or_Java_Developer-cc.pdf). Chapter 8 (page 33) contains an introduction to object oriented programming in Ada. The chapter starts with the following example:

```
type T is tagged record
   V, W : Integer;
end record;

type T_Access is access all T;

function F (V : T) return Integer;

procedure P1 (V : access T);

procedure P2 (V : T_Access);
```

The following page describes an example on how to call the subprogram `P1`:

```
declare
   V : T;
begin
   V.P1;
end;
```

This results into the following error: `object in prefixed call to "P1" must be aliased (RM 4.1.3 (13 1/2))`. If I replace `procedure P1 (V : access T);` with `procedure P1 (V : in out T);` the example is successfully compiled. Is this a typo in the document?

Comment: Another workaround is to declare  V : aliased T;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ARM 4.1.3(13.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-1-3.html#p13.1) was introduced in the 2005 revision in [AI95-00252](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ais/ai-00252.txt?rev=1.16&raw=N) and [AI95-00407](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ais/ai-00407.txt?rev=1.9&raw=N) (I get the impression, as part of a cleanup).

I’d say that the document is wrong. Perhaps this part of the material was developed before Ada 2005.

---

It is true that, under some circumstances, a tagged object is automatically aliased: [ARM 3.10(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-10.html#p9) says

> [...] a formal parameter or generic formal object of a tagged type is defined to be aliased.

So, this is legal:

```ada
declare
   procedure Proc (Param : in out T) is
   begin
      Param.P1;
   end Proc;
   V : T;
begin
   Proc (V);
end;
```

Comment: I was under the impression that tagged types were automatically aliased.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @Jere, see update (I did what felt like a fairly intensive trawl through the ARM to find this!)

Comment: Gotcha, so the use of the access variable is what makes it different.  Oddly GNAT doesn't fully seem to support the implicit aliased-ness of tagged types.  If I want to take 'Access of Param for example, it won't let me unless I change the signature of Proc to use Param : aliased in out T even thought T is tagged and used as a formal parameter

Comment: @Jere, I think they're guaranteed to be passed by reference. Perhaps your idea comes from that?

Comment: @Álex Actually, I believe I had seen it posted by an ARG member on comp.lang.ada.  Simon found the RM section for it as well.